# Is it possible to "validate" a simulator without comparing it with the actual tool?

Tags: projects, validation

I am developing a simulator for a data mining tool. The simulator will be an abstract version of the tool so that people can perform their experiments easily.

I am doing this project for a post Masters Degree and "verification and validation" are a part of the report. Please note that this is not a research degree and the projects are fixed term. So my project time cannot be extended. Also, its not a research project so a publication is not required.

**Problem:**

The problem is that I don't have enough time left for the project and my simulator is not realistic enough to validate with the real tool. I asked the director of our program and he told me that I should ask my stakeholders to limit the scope of the implementation and I should validate against a limited scope. But whenever I ask one of my stakeholders(who will be using the simulator), he says that I cannot validate my simulator against the real tool unless I do all of the implementation. I asked him to restrict the scope of validation(only for the report) so that I can put the validation in my report. He said that we can ask my supervisor (who is on vacation for the next three weeks and isn't responding to emails).

I could try and finish the implementation by spending my weekends and nights on it but even then I will not be able to put the validation in my report because the report deadline is a month before the project deadline.

Do you have any suggestions for the validation of my simulator ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it mainly is about the contents of your research and not about academia itself. It **may** be on-topic on [datascience.se] or [stats.se]. Possible aspects that are not field-specific may (such as how to deal with impossible goals when your supervisor is not available) may be on-topic here though.

Comment: I posted this question on programmers stack exchange but they said that it was off topic because its related to academia and I should post it here.

Comment: Well it is related to academia and some questions related to your problem are on-topic here but your main question (How do I validate my simulator?) is certainly not on-topic here. I am sorry that you have been passed from pillar to post (and please check the sites I recommended to avoid this happening again), but we are simply not equipped for handling your question.

Comment: Can you publish your code on public repositories such as github and perhaps some people will extend your work in the future after you finish the thesis?

Comment: I could but only after I have graduated and received permission from my stakeholders. Any suggestions for my situation?

Comment: Things you can do:
1) Conduct a thorough sensitivity analysis so you know what drives the model and how variable the results may be.
2) Validate against qualitatively defined "expected behaviour" in more general terms, rather than against specific data.